# How can to remove user streamer in a videocall - WebRTC?

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, webrtc, recordrtc

Is it possible to remove or kick one or more user streamer in WebRTC? I am also using `RecordRTC`.

Can anyone give some idea or sample snippet on how to implement this function?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can simply send a signal message to that user via the signalling server and close his peer connection and stream. after that show an alert to inform that "You have been kicked out from this meeting"

Comment: Do you have example code for this? I am still stuck.